# Traversing the linked list using pretty printers in GDB

Tags: linked-list, gdb, pretty-print

I have a linked list pretty printer which takes the input from command prompt. 
E.g., print xyz

My code is something like below:

```
class Randomcalss:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = int(val)

    def to_string(self):
        return "printing linked list:"

    def children(self):
        for field in self.val.type.fields():
            key = field.name
            val = self.val[key]
            yield key,val.dereference()
```

It does work as expected, and prints:

```
 printing linked list:= {head = {next = 0x625590, prev = 0x623c70}}
```

But if I want to traverse the linked list and proceed further what do I do.
Because every time I try to access head['next'] it says head is a string and string indices must be integers.

Cant I do something like self.val[key] to access next node of head too?

Comment: In C++ you can do something like this `p head->next`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I wanted a way to traverse the linked list in GDB pretty printers.

Comment: You can use command `set print pretty on` and after that whatever you wint using `print` or `p` will be in pretty format

Comment: From the command prompt, I just want to pass the head and it should traverse all the nodes and display their respective contents. So print   head - >next will just give me the address and not the contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do val.dereference()['next'] and this will give you address of next member of the list. You can cast the value obtained(if required) and traverse further.